# Ms Word - Field - Get a Simple Calculated Date

Tags: ms-word

I want a field to have Yesterdays Date.
What Formula should I Put in the Field Formula

Like, if Todays 20th,  the Formula should produce 19

Comment: this could be a (good) question to ask in [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com)